# IFS of compact set

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, fractals, iterated-function-system

In complete metric space $X$, there exists a unique non-empty compact set of $X$ called attractor for any iterated function system (IFS). But, is there an IFS for any nonempty compact subset of $X$?

Comment: Every compact subset of $X$ is complete, so yes.

Comment: @dan-rust Your argument does not solve the question, which is to find an IFS whose attractor is the given compact subset.

Comment: Sorry, the question, as phrased, was unclear.

Comment: Self-similar sets have no isolated points so, no. On the other hand, given any compact set $C$ and an $\varepsilon>0$, there is a self-similar set whose distance from $C$ in the Hausdorff metric is less than $\varepsilon$. Thus, you may approximate any set you want with an IFS.